# What is the best way to listen to music in my shower/bathroom from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod, music, airplay, speakers

I have all of my music catalogged in iTunes, and have no intentions of changing the software I use to listen to it. Therefore, I came here to gain some advice on the easiest/cheapest way to listen to my music in my shower. It's a big plus if I can use a remote to change the song while showering. Previously, I used my iPod touch docked in batter-powered speakers placed on my bathroom counter. The speakers had an included remote. This method worked great, but my iPod has since been broken and I do not think it was a great idea to expose it to the high-levels of water vapor in the first place. Would the cheapest method be purchasing another iPod? Or would an Air-play supported speaker system be the best option?

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to learn to sing in the shower!

Comment: @Neil +1 -- That is arguably the cheapest solution.  ;]

Comment: @Austin - It's the iPerson! (Or maybe the iI!)

Comment: @Neil The iI -- brilliant!  You should trademark that pronto!

Comment: @Neil however it always sounds louder to the people outside the shower, so when you start singing Lady Gaga *quietly* its actually quite loud and audible for everyone else in the house,of course I've *never* experienced *anything* like this.

Answer (score 3):

You generally shouldn't bring any electronics into an area with that much water vapor on a regular basis unless they are labeled for such use.

If you search for `waterproof speakers` [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=waterproof+speakers) you'll find many affordable options, including several that are designed specifically for iPods.

Answer (score 1):

Airport Express + Waterproof speakers (mounted). Use AirPlay to play from your iOS device or Mac (iTunes).

That way you can keep your Mac out of the bathroom if you want to play from iTunes.